# Alexa Audio Player: Quit utterance does not work

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

During the playing of an audio file using the audio player, if a user utters "Alexa, quit", then the Alexa device will continue to play the audio.

It can be seen that no request is sent to the fulfilment code. You only get an 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackStopped' event, on uttering the command. Then immediately after, an 'AudioPlayer.PlaybackStarted' can be seen.

Could this be an oversight of Amazon, or is there something extra that needs to be done to enable this command during audio player playback?

"Alexa, quit" otherwise works when outside of the audio player, i.e. when in 'question and answer' ssml based scenarios. In these scenarios, a request of the 'SessionEndedRequest' type can be seen on saying "Alexa, quit".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `AMAZON.PauseIntent` is implemented correctly. From Amazon developer site:

> ...when your skill is not in an active session but is playing audio,
>   or was the skill most recently playing audio, utterances such as
>   'stop' send your skill an AMAZON.PauseIntent instead of an
>   AMAZON.StopIntent

Your described scenario works with my audio skill so i don't think it's a bug with alexa.

Comment: During audio player use, I do see the 'pause intent' when saying "stop". However, my issue is around saying "quit". On saying "quit" during the audio player no intent is received. Is this the scenario under which you are seeing the 'pause intent'?

Comment: Hmm i see... You can edit the built in Amazon intents, so what happens if you add "quit" to the AMAZON.StopIntent or AMAZON.CancelIntent ?

Comment: Having tried this, it only allows the user to say "Alexa, ask [skill name] for quit" during the audio player. Saying "Alexa, quit" during the audio player still has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon replied to my email inquiry and confirmed that this exact case is expected behavior:

> This is actually working as intended. The original reasoning behind
>   this is that using exit takes you out of the GUI experience so you can
>   do something else on screen while you continue to hear the audio in
>   the background until you say “stop”. This works the same across all
>   skills that use AudioPlayer. Most customers tend to use “stop, so as
>   long as the audio and visuals stop then, then we are good.